# Multisite Rails/Jruby site has ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified database configuration does not specify adapter issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, jruby, multi-database

Trying to have web app change schemas based on a drop down. I have a feeling that I am not pulling in the drop down selection.

Model:

```
class MyApp < ActiveRecord::Base 
def initialize(dbase)
 @dbase = fdbase
 if @dbase == 'DB01'
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection"#{Rails.env}"
 else
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection"#{Rails.env}_#{@fc}"
end
end
end
```

controller:

```
class MyAppController < ApplicationController
before_filter :initialize_remote_user

   def self.search(name)
     @results = MyApp.search(params[:name])
     @dbase = params[:dbase].inspect
     c = MyApp.new(@dbase)
     result = c.last 
    end

   def result
     c = MyApp.new(@dbase)
     result = c.last
     @results =  MyApp.where("name = ?",params[:name]).order("item_scan_date ASC")
     puts @results.inspect
   end


   def update
    @results = MyApp.Where(name: name_params)
    @dbase = params[:dbase].inspect
    end

   def change
     @results = MyApp.Where(name: name_params)
     @dbase = params[:dbase].inspect
     end

   def show
    @dbase = params[:dbase].inspect
    c = MyApp.new(@dbase)
    result = c.last
   end

   def create
   end

   def new
   end

   def index
     @dbase = params[:dbase].inspect
     c = MyApp.new(@dbase)
     result = c.last
   end

  private

  def name_params
     params.require(:name).permit(:name)
  end

  def dbase_params
     params.require(:dbase).permit(:dbase, :id)
  end

end
```

the drop down is on my nav bar and pulled in in _nav.html.erb: below is the _dbform.html.erb

```
<div id="float_right">
<%= form_for @dbase do |f| %>
<%= f.select( :dbase, options_for_select([['DB01','DB01'],['DB02','DB02'],['DB03','DB03'],['DB04','DB04']])) %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

database.yml which production and development are the same.

```
# Uses RubyGem-activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: myhost
  database: DB01
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306

development_DB2:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: myhost
  database: DB02
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306

development_DB3:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: myhost
  database: DB03
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306

development_DB4:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: myhost
  database: DB04
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the controller code it would probably be more useful to see the actual back-trace of the error ... since from that one can likely figure out the AR and AR-JDBC versions, anyway as a blind shot try this :

```
if @dbase == 'DB01'
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "#{Rails.env}".to_sym
else
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :"#{Rails.env}_#{@dbase}"
end
```

... that is using symbols + `@dbase` seems to be the variable we need